# Parse HTML With C#

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone, html-agility-pack

I'd like to parse html page using C#. There are html pages which contain a lot of html tags, here's a sample of one of them :

```
<span class=text14 id="article_content"><!-- RELEVANTI_ARTICLE_START --><span ></b>The 
     most important component for <a
     class=bluelink href="http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-
     3284752,00.html%20"' onmouseover='this.href=unescape(this.href)' 
     target=_blank>Israel</a>'s
     security is its special relations with the American administration, and especially with its generous purse. When the Netanyahu government launches a great outcry against the <a  ...
```

but I'd only like to get the content wrapped by the `<span class=text14 id="article_content">` tag.
 At first I've thought about using preg match, but then realized it's not efficient at all.
I've later read about **Html Agility Pack** and **FizzlerEx** -
i'd like to know whether it's possible to get the text wrapped by the specific tag i've mentioned using these tools, and i'd be grateful if someone could tell me how fast this task could be performed.

Comment: Please search and check out samples for HtmlAgilityPack. "How fast" - I believe parsing would be `O(length_of_html)` and lookup speed will depend on your actual criteria to search, but likely `O(1)` if you just need to search by `id`.

Comment: First of all, thank for the answer, but what do you mean by "lookup speed will depend on your actual criteria to search?" , what criteria are you talking about ?

Comment: Your sample element is "span with class and ID" - it is not clear what you criteria to pick that particular element is. Most likely just `id` is enough as it is unique in each document - so `O(1)` unless HtmlAgilityPack does not optimize that search.

Comment: Moving through the DOM with HtmlAgilityPack is using XPath so its really simple and easy, if you know the structure of the page you can do it with only couple of commands. Not sure about the speed though. Never had the need to test it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward using [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex):

```
var markup = @"<span class=text14 id=""article_content""><!-- RELEVANTI_ARTICLE_START --><span ></b>The most important component for <a class=bluelink href=""http://www.ynetnews.com/articles/0,7340,L-3284752,00.html%20""' onmouseover='this.href=unescape(this.href)' target=_blank>Israel</a>'s security is its special relations with the American administration, and especially with its generous purse. When the Netanyahu government launches a great outcry against the</span>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(markup);

var content = doc.GetElementbyId("article_content").InnerText;

Console.WriteLine(content);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, the markup you defined is just a sample of a page i'd like to parse , but it's still helpful. Thanks once again